# Several operations inside of a single MongoDB query

Tags: database, pymongo

Is it possible to alter more than one collection in a single query with MongoDB?

A SQL example:

```
begin
update table_1 set some_field=1;
update table_2 set a_different_field=2;
commit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use db.eval for something like that. With db.eval you can execute javascript on the server.

You can find more info about it at the [mongoDB website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using%7B%7Bdb.eval%28%29%7D%7D).